# SQL query returns 0 for datagridview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a select statement that populates a datagridview:

```
da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Month, (Sum(IncCnt)) as IncCnt, (Sum(AllFCR)) as AllFCR, (Sum(Prv)) as Prv, ((SUM(IncCnt)-SUM(AllFCR))/(SUM(IncCnt)-SUM(Prv))) as FCR, ((SUM(ASAT)+SUM(CSAT))/(SUM(SurveyTtl))) as CSAT FROM [tblPLOps_Data] group by Month", ScoreConn)
```

However, it displays a 0 for FCR and CSAT although you can do the math from the first three columns and see that FCR should be .89

I need to display as a percent anyway so I tried:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "p"
```

But that just returned 0%, I also changed to decimal and that just returned 0.0

Then I read online and tried:

```
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
```

But that didn't help either, anyway how to get it to return a value?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
((SUM(IncCnt)-SUM(AllFCR))/(SUM(IncCnt)-SUM(Prv)))
```

and

```
((SUM(ASAT)+SUM(CSAT))/(SUM(SurveyTtl)))
```

are using `INTEGER` division since they are both integers. You need to cast (one of) them to decimal first, ideally the deominator. Here's an example...

```
select 1/2       RETURNS 0
select 1/2.0     RETURNS 0.5000000
select 1.0/2     RETURNS 0.5000000
```

Something like...

```
((SUM(IncCnt)-SUM(AllFCR))/(cast(SUM(IncCnt)-SUM(Prv) as decimal(16,2))))
```

and

```
((SUM(ASAT)+SUM(CSAT))/(cast(SUM(SurveyTtl) as decimal(16,2))))
```

Comment: i should have mentioned I assumed it was some sort of integer vs decimal issue, this worked perfect, thank you!

Comment: No worries at all @user7668852

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please accept it as the answer so that other users will know this question has a solution, and the answer's author will receive credit for putting their time in